project of unity not opening on Windows machine
The project is normal operation in the other PC.
The project is available within the Unity Hub, but when I click to open it, Unity splash screen shows up and immediately disappears and I am back at the Unity Hub again.
I checked the logs and found the following:
[LicensingClient] ERROR Failed to connect to local IPC
[Licensing::Module] Failed to connect to channel: LicenseClient-admin
Error creating external process 'D:/Program Files/Unity 2019.4.36f1/Editor/Data/Resources/Licensing/Client/Unity.Licensing.Client.exe' : 系统找不到指定的文件。

Error cleaning up external process: 句柄无效。

[Licensing::Module] Failed to launch LicensingClient: D:/Program Files/Unity 2019.4.36f1/Editor/Data/Resources/Licensing/Client/Unity.Licensing.Client.exe
IPC channel to LicensingClient doesn't exist; falling back to Legacy licensing
[LicensingClient] ERROR Failed to disconnect local IPC connection

LICENSE SYSTEM [2024611 20:8:47] No start/stop license dates set

LICENSE SYSTEM [2024611 20:8:47] Next license update check is after 2034-06-11T19:38:31


LICENSE SYSTEM [2024611 20:8:47] Current license is already valid and activated. Skipping license activation process (Provided username/password will be ignored).
Built from '2019.4/staging' branch; Version is '2019.4.36f1 (660c164b2fc5) revision 6687766'; Using compiler version '191627012'
OS: 'Windows 11  (10.0.22631) 64bit Professional' Language: 'zh' Physical Memory: 32605 MB
BatchMode: 0, IsHumanControllingUs: 1, StartBugReporterOnCrash: 1, Is64bit: 1, IsPro: 1
[Package Manager] Server::Start -- Port 54396 was selected
D:\workspace\ed_client\Packages\com.unity.services.core@1.0.1)

[Subsystems] No new subsystems found in resolved package list.
[Package Manager] Done registering packages in 0.13s seconds
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 654.04 ms, found 41 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.
Initialize engine version: 2019.4.36f1 (660c164b2fc5)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path D:/Program Files/Unity 2019.4.36f1/Editor/Data/Resources/UnitySubsystems
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path D:/workspace/ed_client/Assets
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]
    Renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 (ID=0x1f0a)
    Vendor:   
    VRAM:     3961 MB
    Driver:   27.21.14.5671
Initialize mono
Mono path[0] = 'D:/Program Files/Unity 2019.4.36f1/Editor/Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = 'D:/Program Files/Unity 2019.4.36f1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/unityjit'
Mono config path = 'D:/Program Files/Unity 2019.4.36f1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,server=y,suspend=n,address=127.0.0.1:56436
ImportWorker Server TCP listen port: 54402
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Registering precompiled unity dll's ...
Register platform support module: D:/Program Files/Unity 2019.4.36f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WindowsStandaloneSupport/UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll
Registered in 0.000571 seconds.
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 172.87 ms, found 41 plugins.


Unloading 56 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 6743.
Total: 12.373000 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.526100 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.137200 ms MarkObjects: 8.041600 ms  DeleteObjects: 3.667600 ms)

gi::BakeBackendSwitch: Clear() active clients.
[EnlightenBakeManager] m_Clear = false;
[00:00:00] Enlighten: Precompute started.
[00:00:00] Enlighten: Finished 1 Layout Systems job (0.00s execute, 0.00s integrate, 0.05s wallclock)
[00:00:00] Enlighten: Finished 1 Tetrahedralize Probes job (0.00s execute, 0.00s integrate, 0.05s wallclock)

[Optix] Number of Devices = 2
Crash!!!
SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: 'D:/Program Files/Unity 2019.4.36f1/Editor/Data/Mono;.;D:\workspace\ed_client;D:\Program Files\Unity 2019.4.36f1\Editor;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;SRV*C:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;', symOptions: 534, UserName: 'admin'


A crash has been intercepted by the crash handler. For call stack and other details, see the latest crash report generated in:
 * C:/Users/jiaod/AppData/Local/Temp/Unity/Editor/Crashes

in my folder, only found "D:\Program Files\Unity 2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\Resources\Licensing\Client\Unity.Licensing.Client.exe.bak".
unity version is 2019.4.36f1.
Do you guys have any idea what is going on and how can I fix this (beside reinstall Unity Hub, which I already did and did not help)

Are you sure the license is ok? You could create a new Unity project and drag all the assets, scenes, scripts, etc from the old project into the new project.

Sounds like you need to send it to unity or investigate why it couldnt open the ports it needed to do its own internal checks

Any more info in C:/Users/jiaod/AppData/Local/Temp/Unity/Editor/Crashes?

above text is Editor.log, in C:/Users/jiaod/AppData/Local/Temp/Unity/Editor/Crashes，but it's too long by 51469 characters.
C:\Users\jiaod\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log just like above

I have reinstalled my os of windows11 more times. final, i restalled win10, it become fine.
